# Unity Firebase Xcode Messaging. First game start error

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, xcode8

Firebase Unity SDK v.3.0.3
Unity 5.4.2f2
Xcode 8.3

I create a iOS build. When first start the game, you receive the following error.

```
2017-06-05 15:51:32.503767+0700 tacticool[1549:942648] -[UIApplication messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f79ce0
2017-06-05 15:51:32.589532+0700 tacticool[1549:942648] Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: -[UIApplication messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f79ce0
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x1c2c3b55 <redacted> + 152
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x1b54b067 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x1c2c8fd1 <redacted> + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x1c2c70c3 <redacted> + 696
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x1c1efdc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
    5   tacticool                           0x00a66b4b -[FIRMessaging defaultInstanceIDTokenWasRefreshed:] + 162
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x1c26fdb9 <redacted> + 10
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x1c26f6f9 <redacted> + 382
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x1c26f4e1 <redacted> + 40
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x1c2ca309 <redacted> + 1242
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x1c1d30f5 _CFXNotificationPost + 540
    11  Foundation                          0x1cb70bab <redacted> + 450
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x1c27f803 <redacted> + 20
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x1c27da55 <redacted> + 282
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x1c27df2d <redacted> + 1124
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x1c1d11af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x1c1d0fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x1d97bb41 GSEventRunModal + 80
    18  UIKit                               0x21552e13 UIApplicationMain + 150
    19  tacticool                           0x000f0b9b main + 202
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x1b9be4eb <redacted> + 2
)
2017-06-05 15:51:32.591642+0700 tacticool[1549:942648] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f79ce0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c2c3b3d 0x1b54b067 0x1c2c8fd1 0x1c2c70c3 0x1c1efdc8 0xa66b4b 0x1c26fdb9 0x1c26f6f9 0x1c26f4e1 0x1c2ca309 0x1c1d30f5 0x1cb70bab 0x1c27f803 0x1c27da55 0x1c27df2d 0x1c1d11af 0x1c1d0fd1 0x1d97bb41 0x21552e13 0xf0b9b 0x1b9be4eb)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Do I miss something in XCode? Or have something to check in Unity?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The thing is, if we use cocoaPods to solve the dependencies we don't have any problem/crash. Since we are using Unity Cloud Build and CocoaPods is not supported there we have our own a Post Build Process to add Firebase frameworks. 
For that step we downloaded Firebase frameworks from the website, uncompress the files, add the dependencies, etc. etc. And there is where we get the crash.
But now I see that the firebase files downloaded by Cocoa are different that the files downloaded on the website. So I am using the Cocoa files, and seems like is working.

Comment: how are you installing firebase dependencies? At the end I used CocoaPods resolved dependencies instead of the latest iOS firebase framework.

Comment: At this stage we do not use Unity Cloud Build. I used CocoaPods. Yesterday I tried to compile Firebase Messaging Quickstart project [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/messaging/testapp) but it's crash on same error. Error occurs when you first access FirebaseMessaging.
About CocoaPods. Firebase Unity SDK integrate CocoaPods automati

Comment: I found solution. [link] (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/87)

Comment: cool! that is the solution! you can answer your own question and mark it as resolved! I will upvote it!

Comment: please post this as an answer so others can find it easily.